# Apply new colour (with Gradient) to Win Forms button onClick

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've come across several methods of applying gradient styles to objects in a windows form application. All the methods involve overriding the OnPaint method. However, I am looking the change the style at runtime based on validation.

How can I apply the new gradient style to an already rendered button (like I can with BackColor)?

R,
C.

**UPDATE: This is the code I am currently using. It appears to have no effect**

```
private void Button_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawString("This is a diagonal line drawn on the control",
            new Font("Arial", 10), System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, new Point(30, 30));
        g.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, btn.Left, btn.Top,
            btn.Right, btn.Bottom);

        this.btn.Invalidate();
    }
```

Being called by

```
btn.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.Button_Paint);
```

**FURTHER UPDATE WITH CURRENT CODE**

```
private void Button_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
g.DrawString("This is a diagonal line drawn on the control",
        new Font("Arial", 10), System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, new Point(30, 30));
g.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, btn.Left, btn.Top,
        btn.Right, btn.Bottom);
}

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
btn.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.Button_Paint);();
btn.Invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this. One, as SLaks said, you need to draw the gradient in your `Paint` event handler. This would look something like this (my example here is a bit messy for the sake of brevity):

```
private void Button_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    if (MyFormIsValid()) {
        g.DrawString("This is a diagonal line drawn on the control",
            new Font("Arial", 10), System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, new Point(30, 30));
        g.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, btn.Left, btn.Top,
            btn.Right, btn.Bottom);
    }
    else {
        g.FillRectangle(
            new LinearGradientBrush(PointF.Empty, new PointF(0, btn.Height), Color.White, Color.Red),
            new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, btn.Size));
    }
}
```

Also, you need to do your validation and redraw the button when it is clicked:

```
btn.Click += Button_Click;
```

...

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoValidations();
    btn.Invalidate();
}
```

Of course, you'll have to implement the `DoValidations()` and `MyFormIsValid()` methods.

Here's the whole thing as a runnable sample program: http://pastebin.com/cfXvtVwT

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting nothing happening. Stepping through my code I can confirm that the two lines (adding the new PaintEventHandler and calling Invalidate()) are being hit. However, the function Button_Paint is not being called. I've even added a Refresh() to the button with no change.

Comment: Odd... I have this running as a sample application... I'll post the whole thing.

Comment: Found out why yours works ... you're creating the button at runtime. Mine is created at design time. I guess I'll have to create it as runtime as well.

Comment: It seems unlikely that creating the control in the designer is the problem. It's more likely to be related to where you're attaching the event handlers, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It is ... having moved it to being created at runtime has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As you've seen, you need to handle the `Paint` event.

You can set a boolean in your class to indicate whether to draw the gradient or not.

Comment: I'll include code I use to override the form (at render) shortly. I'm still not sure how to override the button Paint event with anything similar.