# How to change BackColor to gradient in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, gradient, backcolor

How to change the backGround Color in windows Form To gradient ?

Its my Code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Color_Form_Paint(null, this);
}

private void Color_Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle,
                                                   Color.Gray,
                                                   Color.Black,
                                                   90F))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

I want to change the backColor gradient by Click On button. But I dont know how to fire Painting event and send it my new gradient Color.
Thanks for any helping

Comment: you should override `OnPaint`.

Comment: I think your question is duplicate of this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343366/apply-new-colour-with-gradient-to-win-forms-button-onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343366/apply-new-colour-with-gradient-to-win-forms-button-onclick)

Comment: @Farshad I dont know how to call Paint event my self, and send my Color to it